# How do I set an element of an already-defined vector function to some expression?

Tags: functions, vector

I'm defining a vector whose elements depend on time, *i.e.* I'm defining a real vector function of real elements that depend on the real scalar time variable. The vector function is named `pdemand` and I initially define it as `pdemand[t_] := {a, b, c}` in Mathematica (*i.e.* as a time-independent vector).

Now suppose I want to change the second element of that function from `b` to `t^2`. To begin with, as we know to select an element of a constant vector defined as `v = {a, b, c}` we type `v[[2]]`; and as we also know to call a scalar function defined as `f[t_] := t^2` we type `f[t]`. However, for `pdemand` it looks like I have to both specify it is a time-dependent function as well as the element to choose, as `pdemand[t][[2]]`.

All of this is shown in the following figure.

[image]

So good so far. Now suppose I want to select the second element of `pdemand` and set it to `t^2`. I tried typing `pdemand[[2]] = t^2`, `pdemand[t][[2]] = t^2` and `pdemand[t_][[2]] := t^2` but they failed, as shown in the following figure.

[image]

How can I successfully set the second element of the vector function `pdemand[t]` (currently set to `b`) to `t^2`?

Comment: This is not really doable in general. The issue is that `pdemand[t_]` could be an arbitrarily complicated function, where you have no way of knowing what to replace to change the second element. I guess you could hack something together for simple cases, but I am not sure that is the best solution: Changing the function definition in the middle of the program will likely lead to confusion, I would suggest you simply update the original definition instead, or create a new function (that could even call `pdemand` internally to get some of its elements)

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

pdemand[t_] := {a, b, c}
```

To replace the second part of `pdemand` use [`ReplacePart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html)

```
ReplacePart[pdemand[t], 2 -> t^2]

(* {a, t^2, c} *)
```

If the second part is a symbol and you want to [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) the symbol's value use

```
Evaluate[pdemand[t][[2]]] = t^2;

b

(* t^2 *)
```

**EDIT:** If you want to change the definition of `pdemand`, change its [`DownValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html)

```
Clear[b]

DownValues[pdemand]

(* {HoldPattern[pdemand[t_]] :> {a, b, c}} *)

DownValues[pdemand] = 
  ReplacePart[DownValues[pdemand], {1, -1, 2} -> t^2]

(* {HoldPattern[pdemand[t_]] :> {a, t^2, c}} *)

pdemand[1]

(* {a, 1, c} *)
```

Comment: Note that your last example won't work as expected: `pdemand[1]` returns `{a, t^2, c}`, not `{a, 1, c}`

Comment: @LukasLang - The last example sets the definition for `b` it doesn't change the definition of `pdemand`. To get the result that you expect, use `pdemand[t] /. t -> 1` after `b` is defined.